# Handing an async call to Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following method inside my database.swift file:

```
func GetTestData(arg: Bool, completion: ([Tweet]) -> ()) {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var tweets = [Tweet]()

        db.collection("tweets").getDocuments() {
            querySnapshot, error in

            if let error = error {
                print("unable to retrieve documents \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else{
                print("Found documebts")
                tweets = querySnapshot!.documents.flatMap({Tweet(dictionary: $0.data())})
            }

        }

        completion(tweets)
    }
```

This method connects to `Firestore` retrieve data from a given collection, convert it into an array and then passes it back, I call this function with the following (located within my table view controller):

```
func BlahTest() {

        let database = Database()
        print("going to get documents")

        database.GetTestData(arg: true) { (tweets) in

            self.tweets = tweets

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }


        print("after calling function")        
    }
```

The issue I have is when I run this my code is out of sync, and by that I mean `print("after calling function")` is called before `print("Found documebts")` which tells me it's not waiting for the async call to `Firestore` to finish,  now I'm new to `iOS` development so would someone be willing to help me understand how I go about handling this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using closure block in your `GetTestData()` method. Anything that should be done after execution of this method must be done inside completion:

```
{
    (tweets) in
        self.tweets = tweets
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        // Do rest of stuff here.
}
```

Following are some resource about implementing async/await in swift like other languages:

[1. Async semantics proposal for Swift](https://gist.github.com/oleganza/7342ed829bddd86f740a)

[2. AwaitKit : The ES8 Async/Await control flow for Swift](https://github.com/yannickl/AwaitKit)

[3. Concurrency in Swift: One approach](https://gist.github.com/lattner/31ed37682ef1576b16bca1432ea9f782)

[4. Managing async code in Swift](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f)

Hope this helps :)